# Locked Print settings disapper on workstations

Tags: printing, drivers, roaming-profile, network-printer, printer

we have a RICOH MFD and its queue ison a print servers ; few people accesing it via windows 7 workstations , have issues. They set the Locked print preference in Print Preferences -> one click print preset ; but those locked print settings disappear eventually , within a  day or within even hours; they are using the same workstations all the time but i have no idea whata causing the settings to disappear. Please do let me know of any solutions or where i can look for to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are deploying the printers via GPO and defined the deployment method as "Replace"?

What that would do is essentially delete and recreate the printer every time the GPO processing runs, wiping out the printer user preferences and resetting it.

If this is the case you could try deploying the printers with the "update" or "create" method. See the following technet documentation for details

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732092.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately we are not using any kind of GPO's for printers; will take a look at the article.